# Wifi card range is extremely poor after opening Lenovo G40-80

Tags: lenovo-laptop, wifi-driver

My Lenovo g40-80 was working fine. After opening the motherboard to change thermal paste, wifi networks are no longer detected unless I get close to the router. So I guess the wifi card works, but the problem is in the antenna?

I checked the Wifi adapter again, ensured cable connections. The antenna is inside the screen.

What did I do wrong? How do I diagnose this problem?

## Update

The problem is solved after switching between the two wires connecting the the Wifi card. The Bluetooth problem was solved after enabling all Bluetooth services in Windows Service Manager.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the connectors are seated properly? They are very small, so it can be hard to tell just from looking at it.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many cables does the wifi card accept, and how many are in the laptop?

It's been a while since I opened a laptop, but usually there are two antenna cables in the laptop, and two connectors on the card.

Try switching the antenna connectors and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Did the Bluetooth devices have poor connectivity before the switch? Because your original post didn't mention that.